# How to make a new prediction using rfcv in R

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation

I have used the RandomForest (RF) Package in R for making RF cross validation for proteins data using "rfcv" function.

How can I make a predict for new protein data using object I had from rfcv?

Answer (score 0):

`rfvc` will cross validate the model against some data.
In order to predict some values for other data you need to use the `predict` function.

Given a forest, `rf` and some new data `newdata` call

```
predict(rf, newdata)
```

The detailed [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) give this as an example:

```
data(iris)
set.seed(111)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(iris), replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.8, 0.2))
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris[ind == 1,])
iris.pred <- predict(iris.rf, iris[ind == 2,])
table(observed = iris[ind==2, "Species"], predicted = iris.pred)
## Get prediction for all trees.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't using "randomForest" I used "rfvc" function. when I used predict(rfvcObject, newData ), they give me the following error message: 
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list". !

Comment: That is for cross-validating against some training data. This might help you decide how many predictors to use, to then build another random forest, which you an then use the `predict` function on.